# How to execute a string of bash command with command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, escape-characters, command-substitution

Suppose I have a bash variable like this:

```bsh
tmp1='$(echo foo)'
```

or

```bsh
tmp2='`echo foo`'
```

How to achieve `foo` as result?

I know that removing the command substitution from the string should work, but is there any other way despite this?

Comment: Is the result you want to get a variable called `tmp1` or `tmp2` with the value `foo`? Or do you just want the string `foo` outputted?

Comment: is there some context here? Why would you have the inner command (the `echo`) wrapped in a command substitution in the first place? Why not e.g. have the command by itself in a variable `a='echo foo'` (but see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)), or just run the command substitution immediately `b="$(echo foo)"`?

Comment: I have my PS1 in this format and I wanted to debug it. The PS1 is in such format because I need it executed everytime. @ilkkachu

Comment: @simonmysun, ah, that makes sense, yes.

Comment: Getting `foo` as output is enough for me. I only wantted to exam errors inside. @Kusalananda

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```sh
eval "echo $tmp"
```

or

```sh
bash -c "echo $tmp"
```

I was told by a friend.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "don't do this".  This is simply not a thing that Bash is designed to do:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21

Comment: well, yes, and, well, no. When they have that command substitution somewhere (e.g. in `PS1`), it's already a string, in a variable, and it works just fine. Just that they need to tell the shell to evaluate it as shell syntax, which the shell is perfectly capable of doing, and has a dedicated command for. Not a good idea in general, since it's hard to get right for arbitrary input, but here, it looks like they have a pre-existing command they made themselves, so no untrusted input.